# How to hide the artifactory_password for developers in a project

Tags: java, security, gradle, artifactory

We store/retrieve java libraries from JFrog Artifactory server. We add the following lines in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties to pull project specific private java libraries. How to hide the artifactory_password for developers in a project, can this be globally defined

```
# artifactory_user=bar@foo.com
# artifactory_password=
# artifactory_url=https://foo.jfrog.io/artifactory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure JFrog url and credentials from Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Fill the details in the JFrog section. [image]
Later you can use this configuration as
server = Artifactory.server 'myartifactory'. In this case, credentials will not be visible in the script.

Comment: how about local developer builds, not CI/CD

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you may use encrypted password or Identity Token. User can login to Artifactoyr and get these details from profile edit page on right hand side top corner.